# PHP mysql Tree Child count and List All Child node level wise

Tags: php, mysql, tree, treeview

I have a tree like 
[image: Tree Diagram]

and I want the output for requeted ID for example Admin 
[image: required output.]

my table structure is 
[image: Table/Database Structure]

I have a method that returns Child count level wise but I also want to return the child list level-wise with child count level-wise like 2nd image output required.

```
function childCountLevelWise($conn,$ID, $level){
if ($level>14){
    $count = array(0=>0); 
    return $count;
}
$sql="select * from user_my_tree t where t.parent_ID=".$ID;
$result=returnResults($conn,$sql);
if ($result==null){
    $count = array(0=>0); 
}
else{
    $count = array(0=>0);
    foreach($result as $key=>$row)
    {   
        $count[0]++;
        $children=childCountLevelWise($conn,$row['ID'], $level+1);
        $index=1;
        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
            if ($child==0)
                continue;
            if (isset($count[$index]))
                $count[$index] += $child;
            else    
                $count[$index] = $child;
                $index++;
        }    
    }    
}
return $count;
```

}

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding your structure and data of your database table `user_my_tree` to make it more likely someone answers your question.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will add more detail

Comment: The expected result does not seem correct: what should it look like if multiple nodes have sub-items ? I think you might find answers on this question: [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a way of counting nested sets, I can reproduce your example without using a database with this code:

```
function returnResults($parent)
{
    switch ($parent) {
        case 'root':
            return ['vijay', 'suresh', 'mukesh'];
        case 'vijay':
            return ['manish', 'rohan', 'manu'];
        case 'manish':
            return ['rinku', 'raja', 'vijay2'];
        default:
            return [];
    }
}

function childCountLevelWise($parent, $level, &$result)
{
    $result[$level] = empty($result[$level]) ? [] : $result[$level]; // init array
    if ($level > 14) {
        return; // ignore levels over 14
    }

    $levelResults = returnResults($parent); // get results for this parent
    $result[$level] = array_merge($result[$level], $levelResults); // add to results for this level
    foreach ($levelResults as $child) {
        childCountLevelWise($child, $level + 1, $result); // check for each child at this level
    }
}
```

And calling it and printing the results with this code

```
childCountLevelWise('root', 0, $result);

// print result
foreach ($result as $level => $people) {
    if (!empty($people)) {
        printf('Result for level %d: %s', $level, implode(',', $people));
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Will result in:

```
Result for level 0: vijay,suresh,mukesh
Result for level 1: manish,rohan,manu
Result for level 2: rinku,raja,vijay2
```

From there I think it should be simple enough to modify the `returnResults` function in my example to query the database, although if you're using this on a lot of results you might want to consider the performance costs of this. There are good solutions to having tree structures in the database already, such as the [Nested Set](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/tree.md) in Doctrine.